# What happens to atoms inside a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, condensed-matter, quantum-gravity, neutron-stars, gravitational-collapse

Black holes have very high gravitational force that tends to crush everything. So as we know atoms in a molecule have inter-atomic spacing between them and further electrons also revolve at a certain distance to the nucleus and inside the nucleus there is also some empty space. So does the strong force of a black hole crush them all the way, leaving no space in between them? And, if that happens, then it should give rise to a completely new species of atoms and molecules, right?

Answer (score 12):

Even before you have a black hole, you can have a neutron star.  Here, the gravitational force is enough to cause atoms to collapse, as protons absorb electrons in [reverse beta decay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_capture), making the neutron star essentially a giant nucleus without protons.  If you add mass beyond the maximum stable size of a neutron star, you get a neutron star supernova, and then collapse to a black hole (you can also form black holes directly from a star, of course).

What happens to the atoms on their way to the singularity is not well understood by current research, and the question is in principle unanswerable right now when the volume of the solid becomes smaller than one cubic planck length, as we do not have a universally accepted theory of physics with concrete predictions that is applicable below this length scale.